# Текстовый редактор vim

Tags: vim, редактор-текста

un~
py~

Как убрать создание этих временных файлов работаю в ос виндовс 7

Answer (score 4):

Добавьте в файле `_vimrc` (обычно лежит в каталоге `home` - название каталога и место зависит от операционной системы) следующие строчки:

```
set nobackup
set noswapfile
set noundofile
```